# Maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object in Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, memcached

While working on an appengine project, python/webapp2. We have dict "data" and we will set it to memcache with

memcache.set(some_key, data)

however i keep on getting a RuntimeError maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object. How do you solved this without settings some number in sys.setrecursionlimit(number)?

Comment: Are you sure it's a straight dictionary.  If so then it probably has a reference to itself - though pickle should break that reference.  Alternately you have datastore entities in the dictionary, with reference properties that are cyclical in some fashion.  You should do some basic debugging and work out what is in your dictionary. The problem  is in your data.  If this is happening in the dev environment, then you should be able to work out quickly what is going on using pdb.

Comment: I've a similar problem, although without memcache involved. Not reproducible in the dev environment. Serializing a class that has in it a couple of strings and datetimes, and two lists, each of classes that consist of strings and datetimes. Can not conceive of how there would be cyclical references (and if there were, pickle is supposed to be able to handle, no?)
Out of about 100 such objects, all serialize but one. Will resume debugging tonight to see if I can narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more information, but here's an approach that worked for me. I thought I had the following situation:

- No memcache involved.
- Not reproducible in the dev environment.
- Serializing a class that has in it a couple of strings and datetimes, and two lists, each of classes that consist of strings and datetimes.
- Can not conceive of how there would be cyclical references (and if there were, pickle is supposed to be able to handle, no?)
- Out of about 100 such objects, all serialize but one.

It turns out that I was setting a string-like object, a [NavigableString](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) in one field. This has a reference to the whole parsed HTML document and serializing it caused the overflow.

I ended up being able to debug by using [sys.setrecursionlimit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) to *lower* the stack depth on my home machine.

Then I used a custom pickler, overrode `save(self, obj)` to emit some debugging information, and saw the problem.